# Is a inverse limit of indecomposable again indecomposable?

Tags: homological-algebra, chain-complexes

In truth, I do not need in the general case.

Let $R$ be a ring (associative, with unit element) and let $\mathrm{Comp}(R)$ the *category of complexes* over $\mathrm{Mod}\ R$.

If $\mathbb{N}$ is the natural numbers with the usual partial order and $\{X_i^\bullet, \varphi_{i,j}\colon X_j^\bullet \to X_i^\bullet\}$ is an *inverse system* over $\mathbb{N}$ such that $X_i^\bullet \in \mathrm{Comp}(R)$ is indecomposable, for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$, so is indecomposable $\varprojlim X_i^\bullet$?

**Edit.** Of course, I'm assuming $\varphi_{i,j} \neq 0$ for all $j\geq i \in \mathbb{N}$.

---

**Remark.** A category $\mathcal{C}$ is *complete* if $\varprojlim A_i$ exists in $\mathcal{C}$ for every inverse system $\{A_i , \varphi_{i,j}\}$ in $\mathcal{C}$. The categories $\mathcal{C} = \mathrm{Mod} \ R$ and $\mathcal{C} = \mathrm{Comp}(R)$ are examples of complete categories.

Comment: *Para doto* sounds nice, thank you.

Comment: @WlodzimierzHolsztynski, thank you. "todo" and not "doto" :)

Comment: It's still nice. Sorry for my typo. Thank you again.

Comment: @WlodzimierzHolsztynski, ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $M$ and $M'$ are two $R$-modules with a common submodule $N$ that has a descending chain of submodules
$$N=N_0\supseteq N_1\supseteq N_2\supseteq\dots$$
with zero intersection.

Then if $X^\bullet_i$ is the two term complex
$$\dots\to 0\to N_i\to M\oplus M'\to 0\to\dots,$$
where the differential embeds $N_i$ diagonally into $M\oplus M'$, the inverse limit of the $X^\bullet_i$ is the complex
$$\dots\to 0\to 0\to M\oplus M'\to 0\to\dots,$$
which is decomposable, but it's not too hard to construct cases where all the complexes $X^\bullet_i$ are indecomposable.

For example, for complexes of abelian groups, take $M$ to be the $p$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$, and $M'=\mathbb{Z}_q$ for primes $p\neq q$, and take $N=\mathbb{Z}$ with the chain of subgroups $N_i=2^i\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: J. Rickard, thank you very much. And if we add the hypothesis that each morphism $\varphi_{i,j}\colon X_j^\bullet \to X_i^\bullet$ is an epimorphism?

Comment: @Ogniov: How about taking $X^\bullet_i=\dots\to0\to\mathbb{Z}_p\to\mathbb{Q}_p\oplus\mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z}\to0\to\dots$, so that in the inverse limit the differential is a split monomorphism?

Comment: J. Ricard, I believe in your intuition. But I confess do not quite understand the issue. Thank you very much.